# Quick switching between screen sessions

Tags: gnu-screen

Suppose that I have two screen sessions (`screen_session_a` and `screen_session_b`), both of which have several windows (`window_1` to `window_n`).

The hierarchical layout looks like this:

```
+--+ screen_session_a
|  +- window_0
|  +- window_1
|  +- ..
|  +- window_n
|
+--+ screen_session_b
   +- window_0
   +- window_1
   +- ..
   +- window_n
```

I'm aware that switching between windows within the *same* session can be done efficiently with `<CTRL> A-n`, `<CTRL> A-p`, and so on. But now let's say I want to switch windows from different screen sessions, e.g. from `screen_session_b/window_1` to `screen_session_a/window_1`.

At the moment I would do the following:

- Detach from `screen_session_b` by hitting `<CTRL> A-d`
- Attach `screen_session_a` with `screen -r screen_session_a`
- If `window_1` is not open yet, switch the window: `<CTRL> A-' 1 <CR>`

This is pretty cumbersome, especially if you need to to that very often. So I wondered if there is a more efficient way to switch between windows across *different* screen sessions?

Comment: On a side note: if `screen` can't help with that, maybe `tmux` will? I have not investigated this so this is just a suggestion.

Comment: (C-a C-a) -> "switch to the last window displayed" is not working across sessions?

Comment: @Ghanima unfortunately not. It just switches between the windows of the same session.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible with screen and there is no way to easily work around this limitation of screen. Screen sessions are independent and has no knowledge of other screen session running.

If you need this you can switch to tmux which does have this feature to awitch between sessions.